# Allstar Node Programming

Tags: linux, bash

I'm almost completely new to Linux programming, and Bash Scripts.  I build an amateur radio AllStar node.

I'm trying to create a script that looks at a certain variable and based on that info decides if it should connect or not.  I can use a command: `asterisk -rx "rpt showvars 47168`.  This returns a list of variables and their current values.  I can store the whole list into a variable that I define, in my test script I just called it `MYVAR` but I can't seem to only get the value of one of the variables that's listed.

I talked to someone who knows a lot about Linux programming, and she suggested that I try `CONNECTED="${MYVAR[3]}"` but when I do this, `CONNECTED` just seems to become a blank variable.

What really frustrates me is I have written programs in other programming languages, and I've been told Bash scripts are easy to learn, but yet I can't seem to get this.

So any help would be great.

Comment: Please attach an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

how did you assigned your variable?

It seems to me that you want to work with an array, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar=( $( asterisk -rx "rpt showvars 47168 ) )
echo ${mywar[3]}   # this is your fourth element
echo ${#myvar[@]}  # this is the total of element in your array
```

be careful that index in an array starts at 0

Comment: I think initially I assigned the variable as myvar=`asterisk -rx "rpt showvars 47168` and when it assigned the list that was returned it shows it all on one line, so I'm assuming it took the whole array and made it just a line of text.  I'll try the way you have it listed a little later tonight.

Comment: you get a list  with `myvar=$( command )` 
you get a array with `myvar=( $( command ) )`

Comment: I was able to get it to work the way you listed.  The problem is the command that generates the array seems to generate them in a different order each time, which I never realized until now.  So now I have to figure out how to find the one I want each time, but I have a few ideas on that, which I'll try next week when I'm home.

Comment: *"the command that generates the array seems to generate them in a different order each time"* I'm not sure I understand. maybe, you can accept the answer to close it and open a another question with a [good mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?